# How to access and re-format Jagged Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have 2D array in c#, like this:

```
int[][] 2darray = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

how can I get one column as normal array, like

```
int[] array = 2darray[1][]; //example, not working
```

and have

```
int[] array = {3,4};
```

?
Thanks.

Comment: `int[][]` is a jagged array, not a 2d array.

Comment: What do you expect a "column" to return - the existing answers will give you the Nth array in your jagged array, e.g. `{1, 2}`, if by column you mean the Nth element of each sub-array, e.g. `{1, 3, 5, 7}` you'll need to do more work.

Comment: Are you asking for a column or a row here? `{3,4}` seems to be the second row, whereas it seems to me that, for exemple the first _column_ should be `{1,3,5,7}`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons why your code can't compile

This way it works:

```
int[][] array2d = { new[]{ 1, 2 }, new[]{ 3, 4 }, new[]{ 5, 6 }, new[]{ 7, 8 } };

int[] array = array2d[0];
```

Problems:

- `2darray` is not a valid variable name
- The indexing is wrong
- The initialization of the original array is wrong

EDIT:
As stated by @heltonbiker, if you require all elements of the first column, you can use this:

```
int[] col = array2d.Select(row => row[0]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Looks like OP was mistaken, he wants a column, see comments in original question.

Comment: int[] array = array2d[0];
This is exactly this, what I was looking for. Thanks. 
(array2d is array, which function gets as parametr | 2darray maybe isn't valid name, I wrote it as example. Even the rest, how I thought it could works.)

Answer (score 3):

For an array with two columns and four rows, you can use LINQ this way:

```
using System.Linq;

first_column = _2darray.Select(row => row[0]).ToArray();
```

Note that changing the first or second array will not change the other one.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the only, not even the best solution. But it surely IS a solution.

Comment: (and OP never said he needs to modify original array)

Comment: Didn't catch the column part. My bad. Added a note to your answer clarifying my previous concerns. If you don't like it, please revert. +1

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) and [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) in C#. While they are similar, there is a slight difference. Rows in a jagged array can have a different number of elements, while in a 2D-array they are of the same length. Therefore when working with jagged arrays you need to remember to write handling for a missing column element. I composed a sample console app below to show how both of them work - it uses 0 as a substitute for a missing element, but you can throw an error etc.:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JaggedArrayExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //jagged array declaration
            int[][] array1;

            //jagged array declaration and assignment
            var array2 = new int[][] {
                          new int[] { 1, 2 },
                          new int[] { 3, 4 },
                          new int[] { 5, 6 },
                          new int[] { 7, 8 }
                        };

            //2D-array declaration
            int[,] array3;

            //2D-array declaration and assignment (implicit bounds)
            var array4 = new int[,] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

            //2D-array declaration and assignment (explicit bounds)
            var array5 = new int[4, 2] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

            //get rows and columns at index
            var r = GetRow(array2, 1); //second row {3,4}
            var c = GetColumn(array2, 1); //second column {2,4,6,8}
        }

        private static int[] GetRow(int[][] array, int index)
        {
            return array[index]; //retrieving the row is simple
        }

        private static int[] GetColumn(int[][] array, int index)
        {
            //but things get more interesting with columns
            //especially if jagged arrays are involved
            var retValue = new List<int>();
            foreach (int[] r in array)
            {
                int ub = r.GetUpperBound(0);
                if (ub >= index) //index within bounds
                {
                    retValue.Add(r[index]);
                }
                else //index outside of bounds
                {
                    retValue.Add(0); //default value?
                    //or you can throw an error
                }
            }
            return retValue.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work

```
int[] array = array2d[1];
```

Change the name of the variable to `array2d`, you cannot have variable that starts with number, a variable can start with letter or underscore.